# How to change constraint FOREIGN KEY in mysql 8 from `ON DELETE CASCADE` to `ON DELETE SET NULL` in laravel migration or raw sql

Tags: mysql, laravel

Firstly, my English very bad. Sorry about that.

I have a foreign key in `cards` table like:

```php
$table->foreignId('wallet_id')->constrained('wallets', 'id')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Since some reasons I need change `cascade` to `set null` on that column

I have try (in a new migration):

```php
$table->dropForeign('cards_wallet_id_foreign');
$table->foreignId('wallet_id')
    ->nullable()
    ->onDelete('set null')
    ->change();
```

that run okey but when delete it not set null :((

How I can solve that. Thank you!!

Comment: did you do this in a new migration? You cant just update the existing one.

Comment: @MichaelMano Of course I created a new migration.

Comment: what is the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After collected and try many times I was found the best solution (don't need drop column)

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AlterWalletIdColumnInCardsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('cards_wallet_id_foreign');
            $table->foreignId('wallet_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->change();

            $table->foreign('wallet_id')
                ->on('wallets')
                ->references('id')
                ->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('cards_wallet_id_foreign');
            $table->foreignId('wallet_id')
                ->nullable(false)
                ->change();

            $table->foreign('wallet_id')
                ->on('wallets')
                ->references('id')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not just modify the existing migration, You need to make another one

```
<?php
  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
  
class ChangeSomeTableColumn extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('the_table_you_are_changing', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table
                ->foreignId('wallet_id')
                ->constrained('wallets', 'id')
                ->onDelete('set null')
                ->change();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
          
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the error in the question, of course I created a new migration that's the basic thing

Comment: I had try your answer, but it not work. If have `->constrained('wallets', 'id')` line mysql 8 will throw `SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'wallet_id' (SQL: alter table `cards` add `wallet_id` bigint unsigned null)`

Comment: Secondly `wallet_id` column cannot null => need add `->nullable()` before constrained.

Answer (score 1):

You must change your table migration schema in a new migration, and make sure you set the foreign key field as nullable:

```
$table->integer('wallet_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

and then use `set null` like this:

```
$table->...->onDelete('set null');
```

Comment: Sorry for the error in the question, of course I created a new migration that's the basic thing

Comment: `$table->...->onDelete('set null');`  If it in a new migration, that statement like add a new column. Even I had try `$table->...->onDelete('set null')->change();` and it still not work :((

Comment: Like, add a new column?! what does it mean?

Comment: If you drop the column as you mention in your question, It'll add a new column, so you don't need to `change()` function anymore!

Comment: Thanks you! for your answer. But I expected a solution don't drop column, since my project was deploy

Comment: Do you use the `doctrine\dbal` package?

Comment: It's great, I hope my answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make changes to **FOREIGN KEY** Constraints first you need to drop the previous index of the foreign key and re add only Forign key Constraints to column.

Try this:

```
Schema::table('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //Drop Previous Index
            $table->dropForeign('cards_wallet_id_foreign');

            //Since we want to set null on Delete Or Update
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('wallet_id')->nullable()->change();

            //Adding Only Forign key Constraints to column
            //calling foreignId will re attempt to create a column
            $table->foreign('wallet_id')->references('id')->on('wallets')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('set null')->change();

        });
```